# Mongoose Schema - Set unique element in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*First of all, sorry for my English.*

Hi guys, I want to create a Schema to store datas like this:

```
var list1 = {
    name: "Name of my list 1",
    recipients: [
        {
            email: "email1@example.com",
            name: "Name 1"
        },
        {
            email: "email2@example.com",
            name: "Name 2"
        }
    ]
}

var list2 = {
        name: "Name of my list 2",
        recipients: [
            {
                email: "email2@example.com",
                name: "Name 2"
            },
            {
                email: "email3@example.com",
                name: "Name 3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

But, I want the `obj.recipients.email` was unique in the object, not unique between all objects.

My mongoose schema:

```
var ListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  recipients: [
    {
      name: String,
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: You can't enforce uniqueness of array elements (objects) with unique index. Unique index is works on collection level. However, I'd enforce uniqueness of array objects in application.

Comment: can you tell whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Since I'm not completely aware of your particular application, but always check in application if particular object already exists before adding another one. However, MongoDB do support some helpers to make task easier. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/